# ArrayList or Hashmap in Java Text Files

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, text-files, crud

I'm wondering which to use to write my text file's record into it, ArrayList or Hashmap.

Records in my text file looks like this:

```
1,Alice,34
2,James,12
3,Jim,21
```

I'll be doing adding, deleting, editing, searching in future. Which on should I use to store my data in?

Comment: Learn the difference between a List and a Map in Java then choose one...

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a customized class where each instance is a line from your text file ?

```
class MyRecord{

     private int id;
     private String name;
     private int anotherField;
               //constructors and getters and setters ... 


          }
```

And then use a list of this records wrapped in objects :

```
    List<MyRecord> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then retrieve the records and construct instances of `MyReocrd` that will be added to the list